# Only load styles for a certain page. If page is - Using Timber/Twig

Tags: timber

Using `timber`/`twig` for `wordpress`. Trying to load `JS` but only for a certain page.

I figured this would be something like

```
    {% if page = mypage %}
       <link......./>
    {% endif %]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer to your question is not depending whether you use Timber or not. You should use conditional statements with the combination of WordPress enqueue functions.

You can see the examples of such approach for example here:
http://geoffgraham.me/wordpress-load-files-on-specific-pages/

The topic is broad and you have a variety of solutions you may use here. Nevertheless I hope my answer helps you move into the right direction.